# How do frameworks setup their routes?

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, nginx

In node.js it's the server that takes the request and does something. But where are the entry points for PHP frameworks when you requests special routes (/blog/title vs /server.php?loc=blog/title or something)?

How does the server know to go there without special config school that is a common scenario in shared hosting situations?

Comment: They use a catch-all approach and redirect everything (excluding actual files in the directory structure) using `.htaccess` (mod-rewrite) to `index.php` where they use a router component to direct the request to the relevant controller/method.

Comment: I would love to mark both as correct answers. It look ceejayoz's answer to make me understand Mohammad AbuShady's more complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is quite simple, first of all using a single entry point, which is `index.php` this file analyzes the request, and matches it to a route, then to a controller and action

*Note: To force passing all requests to those entry points, there are some common known rewrites for web servers to pass the `URI` to the `index.php`*

Each framework has it's method, some use an argument, like

```
/index.php/controller/action => /index.php?uri=/controller/action
```

Then in your code you can get the path using `$_GET['uri']`

Another method which is becoming more popular is using a query string, like

```
/index.php/controller/action => /index.php?/controller/action
```

Then to access it this time you need to use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` holder.

After getting your `URI` you try to use routing rules, which are commonly defined in a routing file in the config directory, the framework splits the `URI` by using `/` and try to look for the controller and action in the right place according to the structure, or in special cases some special routes.

For example for a URL `/car/categories` will search for `/app/controllers/car.php` and look for a function called `function categories(){..}` inside the `car.php` *(keep in mind that I'm just assuming a random structure, the path will differ from one framework to another)*.

Some frameworks allow custom routes, like routing

```
/index.php/homepage => staticPagesController#homepageFunction
/index.php/about_us => staticPagesController#aboutusFunction
```

etc..

If you want to understand frameworks more, I can recommend reading [these articles](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/50/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-1) made by "Fabien Potencier" who's the creator of *symfony* and *symfony2*, also *silex* which is kinda like *symfony2*

He starts talking about routing in [chapter four](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/53/create-your-own-framework-on-top-of-the-symfony2-components-part-4)

Answer (score 1):

Typically, one rewrites 404s to the framework's index.php file for handling.

For example, Laravel's Apache httpd.conf/.htaccess config includes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # if not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # and if not a file
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L] # rewrite to index.php
```

Comment: By my experience this is the easiest way to implement routing. Also Zend Framework is relaying on this. (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

Comment: Would I find where the entry point is from their git repo? [https://github.com/laravel/laravel?files=1](https://github.com/laravel/laravel?files=1)

Comment: It's `public/index.php`.

Comment: So these rewrite rules are just standard in the server then? They know to rewrite the root of a site to public/index.php?

Comment: No, you follow the setup instructions for your chosen framework. File location and mechanism can vary from framework to framework.